# How do I serve webp images from my WordPress site but exclude the WP backend/admin

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, apache

For some reason that I cannot fathom, my Chrome installation does not show me webp images from my website. I can see webp images on other sites (I think - how can you tell if you are being served a fallback image instead?), just not my own.

Anyhoo, I have the following code in my .htaccess file to serve webp images to browsers that support it (assuming a webp version of the image exists):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Does browser explicitly support webp?
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome [OR]

    # OR Is request from Page Speed
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Google Page Speed Insights" [OR]

    # OR does this browser explicitly support webp
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp [OR]

    # AND does a webp image exists?
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f

    # THEN send the webp image and set the env var webp
    RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # If REDIRECT_webp env var exists, append Accept to the Vary header
    Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

# Serve Images with correct Mime Type
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
```

How do I exclude the WordPress backend from this (eg, urls beginning with `https://example.com/wp-admin`) because I think it is interfering with my ability to edit images in the WP Media Library.

Comment: Whereabouts are these directives in relation to your existing WordPress (front-controller) directives?

Comment: "how can you tell if you are being served a fallback image instead?" - Check the HTTP response. (In Chrome, check the Object Inspector > Network Traffic)

Comment: That rewrite rule serves .webp content at .jpg or .png URLs.   I'd think you'd want to redirect to a .webp URL instead, maybe with a "see other" status.

Comment: "my Chrome installation does not show me webp images" - So, what do you see? There is actually an error in your current directives that (if executed) would result in _all_ `.jpg` and `.png` images being rewritten to `.webp`, regardless of whether the `.webp` image existed or not (the last condition is being OR'd, not AND'd). However, it would be more efficient to avoid the filesystem check if you can.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Although a redirect would potentially slow the site down if you had many of these images.